# Dynamic route basic example doesn't work

Tags: node.js, dynamic, routes

I'm learning nodejs on openclassrooms a french website and I tried a code which doesn't work. Why?

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

httpServer = http.createServer(function(request,response)
{
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end('Tout va bien');
    app.get('/etage/:etagenum/chambre/', function(request, response) {
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        response.end('Vous êtes à la chambre de l\'étage n°' + request.params.etagenum);
    })
});

httpServer.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it like as below

You need to pass app object to http.createServer()

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
httpServer = http.createServer(app);
app.get('/etage/:etagenum/chambre/', function(request, response) {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    response.end('Vous êtes à la chambre de l\'étage n°' + request.params.etagenum);
})

httpServer.listen(3000);
```